# I try to play a game on Steam but it wont let me

Tags: steam

I'm new to Steam and I'm not used to how Steam works. Basically when I try to play a game by pressing the Play button it sends me to a little screen which says if I have the Steam desktop application, I think what its saying is if I installed steam and is the app on my home screen, both of those things are true so I click "Yes, Steam is installed Play now" and a tiny screen says "Open URL:steam protocol?" I press "Open URL:steam protocol" And it does absolutely nothing, though sometimes the tab loads but after waiting 30 minutes nothing happens, also sometimes the tab doesn't load (most of the time now). I would love to know how to fix this or learn from a mistake I might have made.

Comment: Are you doing this all via the website Steam (through a web browser)?

Comment: Have you tried opening it in Steam (the actual app, not the website) at all? Sounds like this is the website and broken protocol associations.